# Vroom doesn't maintain column types, why?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with integer, double and character columns. Vroom_write doesn't maintain the integer column type, why not?

```
df<-data.frame(x=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=5), y=runif(15), z=as.integer(rep(c("1","2","3"),each=5)))

vroom::vroom_write(df,"test.csv",delim=",")
```

Comment: I either don't understand or can't replicate.  The first row of my CSV file is `A,0.8868861009832472,1` which seems fine ... ?

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks. I mean if you reread the df after vroom has written it and do df%>%str() they're all dbl or chr. The reason I'm bothered about this is a) storage size and b) for converting to duckdb and querying speed. Does it still show integers for you?

Comment: You are writing a CSV file. CSV files have no where to store data types. They are just plain test files. Data types need to be inferred when CSV files are read. If you need specific data types, don't use CSV. Write the data instead using an R binary format like `readRDS`.

Comment: @MrFlick Makes sense, I was wondering where the meta-data would be stored.

Comment: @MrFlick, post as answer?